# A simpler definition of the snake map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I would like to ask whether the following definition of the connecting morphism in the long exact sequence in homology of a pair $(X,A)$ is correct.

First, define relative cycles and boundaries via
$$\begin{aligned} Z_n(X,A) & = \left\{\gamma\in S_n(X)\; :\; \partial _n \gamma \in S_{n-1}(A) \right\} \\ B_n(X,A) & = B_n(X)+S_n(A) \end{aligned}$$
By the third isomorphism theorem there exists an isomorphism
$$i:H(X,A)\cong Z(X,A)/B(X,A)$$
Now start from a relative cycle $z\in Z_n(X,A)$ and take its boundary $\partial z$, which by definition is an element in $S_{n-1}(A)$. This element is furthermore a cycle in $Z_{n-1}(A)$ since $\partial ^2=0$. So we have a map $Z_n(X,A)\rightarrow Z_{n-1}(A)$. The connecting morphism is defined by
$$s:H_n(X,A)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(A),\;\; i([z])\mapsto [\partial z]$$
where the left equivalence class is an element of $Z(X,A)/B(X,A)$ represented by the relative cycle $z\in Z_n(X,A)$, and $i([z])$ is its isomorphic image in $H_n(X,A)$.

> Is this construction correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this construction is correct. In fact, if you work out the general construction for the connection map in the case that we start out with the short exact sequence 
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow C(A)\rightarrow C(X)\rightarrow C(X)/C(A)\rightarrow 0,
\end{equation}
you will discover that it gives the same result: $\partial([z]) = [dz]$. If you want to complete your own construction note that you have to prove that your map is well defined and that it makes the long exact sequence indeed exact. Note that this will be very similar to the general proof concerning the connection map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that the only verification needed here is to check independence of the representative of $[z]$. This is in comparison to the three verifications needed in Hatcher (bottom of page 116 in the published edition). Am I missing anything?

Comment: No that is correct, to check that your map is well defined is much easier than in the general case (as is done on the bottom of page 116). However, you now have a map and claim that this is a connecting map in the long sequence of homology groups. It remains to be checked that this long sequence of homology groups with your connecting map is exact.

Comment: Generally speaking, as soon as one fixes the objects in the long sequence, the snake map is unique because it's defined by universal properties, right? (By fixing I mean picking a realization of kernels and cokernels.)

Comment: I wouldn't know to be honest. I have never done much category theory;)